# How to find last id in a HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my javascript and I need to find the last id of a div in my html document. I can find it by looking at it, but I want it automatic in the JavaScript.

```
<body>
  <div id="start">
    <div id="1">Text</div>
    <div id="2">Text</div>
    <div id="3">Text</div>
    <div id="4">Text</div>
    <div id="5">Text</div>
    <div id="6">Text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
 function setCookie() {
    document.cookie = '1';
 }

 function startPage() {

     var cookieValueInt = parseInt(document.cookie);
     var secondPage = cookieValueInt + 1;
     document.getElementById(document.cookie).style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.getElementById(secondPage).style.visibility = 'visible';
     if (cookieValueInt == 1) {
         document.getElementById('leftarrow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }

 }

 function nextPage() {
     var cookieValueInt = parseInt(document.cookie);
     var secondPage = cookieValueInt + 1;
     var newCookieValue = cookieValueInt + 2;
     document.getElementById(document.cookie).style.visibility = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById(secondPage).style.visibility = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById(newCookieValue).style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.getElementById(newCookieValue + 1).style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.getElementById('leftarrow').style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.cookie = newCookieValue;


 }

 function previousPage() {
     var cookieValueInt = parseInt(document.cookie);
     var secondPage = cookieValueInt + 1;
     var newCookieValue = cookieValueInt - 2;

     document.getElementById(document.cookie).style.visibility = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById(secondPage).style.visibility = 'hidden';
     document.getElementById(newCookieValue).style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.getElementById(newCookieValue + 1).style.visibility = 'visible';
     document.cookie = newCookieValue;
     cookieValueInt = parseInt(document.cookie);
     if (cookieValueInt == 1) {
         document.getElementById('leftarrow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
 }
```

Comment: @jantimon Not true in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using jQuery and use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var attrId = $('#start').children('div:last-child').attr('id');

 });
```

Also, watch out as yor HTML isn't valid as you are missing a < from the closing div tag.

Comment: God, what is it with people and using jQuery for *everything*?

Comment: because it abstracts the browser inconsistancies.  If you want to write reams and reams of code that someone else has already written (and unit tested), you're more than welcome too.

Comment: If you look at my answer, it is two lines. TWO LINES. Yours is three. jQuery is longer. Nyah. (besides, jQuery 2 is the dumbest thing to happen on the internet...)

Comment: As i said it abstracts the browser inconsistancies,  IE7 doesn't support querySelectorAll, you still have to add a 3rd party library to make document.querySelectorAll available in IE7.

Comment: Stuart do i need to link in my html to the jQuery ore can i use the same link as the javascript?

Comment: Add <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript></script> to your head tag - after any CSS styles

Answer (score 1):

Do not use numbers as IDs. While it is technically valid in HTML5, it is a poor use of IDs and very prone to accidental duplicates. I would suggest using `<div id="someprefix_1">` and so on. You can always take the ID and trim off the prefix to get the number.

That aside, this will work well (except in IE7 and below):

```
var divsWithIDs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]"),
    lastDiv = divsWithIDs[divsWithIDs.length-1];
```

EDIT: If you combine this with the prefix idea, you can easily get "the last element with that kind of ID":

```
var divsWithPrefixedIDs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='someprefix_']"),
    lastDiv = dovsWithPrefixedIDs[divsWithPrefixedIDs.length-1];
```

Comment: where shoud i put in the cod?

 var divsWithIDs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]"),
    lastDiv = divsWithIDs[divsWithIDs.length-1];

Comment: Wherever it is that you need to access the last element.

Comment: sorry for behing a noob but i need it for presing a buttom on next page can you help me whit that and put a alert on i? pls write the code so i understand more and realy thanks alot for the help

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use the container:

```
var parentEl = document.getElementById("start");
var id = parentEl.children(parentEl.children.length-1).id;
```

In addition, you should not use numbers as IDs, see answer of Kolink.
edit: corrected code

Answer (score 0):

Using getElementsByTagName and fetching the last one from the array ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Also, my advice is using jQuery :)

Comment: "[Have you tried jQuery?](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)"